# How to use d3 v4 with Polymer 2.0 classes?

Tags: d3.js, ecmascript-6, polymer, es6-class, polymer-2.x

How can d3.js (v4) be used with a Polymer 2.0 element?
Or how to use a library inside a class that already extends another class?

Trying to create a polymer d3 element to take advantage of polymer's two-way data binding and d3's syntax and functions.  So that the data can be bound to a polymer property and passed to the d3.data() function?

Currently declaring d3 in the class returns undefined.  Does the class need to be instantiated with d3 as a parameter?  It seemed to work with Polymer 1.0.  Another approach was to create a function outside of the class and call that but it's ugly.   It would be nice to just use d3 inside the class.

Or is there a cleaner better way?

eg.

```
<script src="../../bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
var d3 = d3; 
debugger; // hits this breakpoint first, and d3 is defined here and below 
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
     <svg id="svg"></svg>
  </template>
  <script>
    class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          data: {
            type: Object,
            observer: '_dataChanged'
          }
        }
      }

      ready: {
        var d3 = d3;  // when it breaks here on the above breakpoint this is defined
        debugger;  // when it hits this breakpoint 2nd, d3 is undefined here and outside the class; what happened? how to scope it in?
      }

      _dataChanged(newValue, oldValue): {
        var circle = d3.select(this.$.svg).data(newValue).enter().append(circle);  //d3 undefined(! how to define?)
      }

    }
    window.customElements.define(MyApp.is, MyApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.d3` is the way as you're loading the script in the global scope. You can load any external script asynchronously or synchronously.

To load it synchronously, just place the `<script>` tag in the `<head>`.

To load it asynchronously, you can add an `load` event listener to the `<script>` tag to do subsequent stuff when the load is completed.

Comment: That worked but also turns out there was an even simpler thing I could do and missed - load d3 before the my-app file gets loaded. (d'oh)
   <script src="/bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>    <link rel="import" href="/src/my-app/my-app.html">

Comment: You need to ensure that the script that runs `window.d3` must run after the `d3` script has been loaded and parsed successfully. Either use `Promise` or the `onload` event for the script:

`<script src="<path_to_d3>/d3.js" onload="doStuff()"></script>`